# Match generic nested object type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, object, recursion, types, nested

Suppose I have a nested object type for defining, let's say, a user:

```js
type TestUser = {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    houses: {
        address: string;
        rooms: {
            floor: number;
            color: string;
            connectedTo: {
                id: number;
            }[];
        }[];
        doors: {
            location: number;
            size: number;
        }[];
    }[];
    tasks: {
        description: string;
        people: {
            nickname: string;
        }[];
    }[];
}
```

I'd like to define a generic function that can take in this type, and then a specification of the nesting properties of the type; for example, in this case, this might look like:

```js
const houseSpecification = [{
    name: 'houses',
    children: [
        // (not all subproperties of the type need to be defined, e.g. note how the 
        // 'tasks' branch is missing altogether)
        {
            name: 'rooms',
            children: [
                {
                    name: 'id',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            name: 'doors',
        },
    ],
}],
```

In each branch, the 'name' property specifies the name of a property of the parent that is an *object array* type. The type of the object in the array is then taken as the source of 'name's for entries in the 'children' property.

I'm looking for a definition of this specification type in some function taking this format for any given object type, e.g. the type of `Spec` in `function myFunction<T extends object>(spec: Spec<T>[])` such that `myFunction<TestUser>` takes `houseSpecification` as its argument.

I have something which I believe should work, but for some reason is seemingly not recursing properly:

```js
// extracts the type of an array, e.g. ArrayType<({ id: string })[]> -> { id: string }
export type ArrayType<T> = T extends (infer U)[] ? U : never;

// gives a union type of all keys in an object that yield an array of objects, 
// e.g. ObjectArrKeys<{ id: string, data: object[], users: object[] }> -> 'data' | 'users'
export type ObjectArrKeys<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object[] ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

// used as `function myFunction<T extends object>(spec: Spec<T, ObjectArrKeys<T>>[])`
export type Spec<T extends object, Q extends ObjectArrKeys<T>> = {
    name: Q;
    children?: Spec<
            ArrayType<T[Q]>,
            ObjectArrKeys<ArrayType<T[Q]>>
    >[]
}
```

I've tested both utilities, `ArrayType` and `ObjectArrKeys`, and they seem to be working correctly. However, Typescript doesn't seem to like the recursion in `Spec`, complaining that `ArrayType<T[Q]>` doesn't match the type `object`, despite the fact that `Q` can only represent of key of `T` that yields an object array.

Is there a simpler way of getting to my end result? Why is Typescript not inferring these types correctly and claiming that it's not specific enough?

Thanks.

Comment: what is `SubcollectionFlattenerRuleset`?

Comment: @TobiasS. Apologies, I had forgotten to change that when adjusting my code for an MRE. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly this should solve the problem:

```
type Spec<T> = {
  [key in ObjectArrKeys<T>]: {
    name: key, children?: T[key] extends (infer I)[] ? Spec<I> : never
  }
}[ObjectArrKeys<T>][]
```

First of all, since `houseSpecification` and the nested `children` properties are arrays, I will also let `Spec` return an array type. I iterate over all keys with array properties and construct a union of all possible `name` and `children` combinations. For each iteration I then take the inferred element type and recursively call `Spec`.

Before passing the nested object into the recursive `Spec` call I again check that `T[key]` really does `extends (infer I)[]`. I think this information got lost before and TypeScript didn't really know that `T[key]` is of type `any[]` even though `ObjectArrKeys` filtered all array keys.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=22&pln=7&pc=1#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAjgTwiBB5ARgKxAYzgEEYYBpEZAZwB4AVAPgQF4EBvYBLhAbTIQCWAOwQBrSlABmCOgF0AXDL6yE4OCCEATKggCGQ5DxUB%20BP0VCQANxAwA3MAC%20PccikzZD4MBRoEAZTR8eiZWDi4XSkERbDxCEnJKWkYFdk5uIV0AWxBFVwAaBHwACwEAG00YDWNFOkjkFTUNbQQACmFJWwQASQBKIwRTQIIabqYLa1t0xyceWIJiUgpqENkjb2AAegAqBABaA8Oj45PTo4RtzY3fdDoQKjgAVSousPSuTJzFB5hhAHMHNxVFldOVvnBfkIAe8EMUoABXF5URThIHcXSaSr3ZEIH7-QForgwKBQLI41GEoGSMokmAWeFZLC2AmU7j4KA0um4iH4mGs9lCSyEECaOhQFF81ncASaemM5mSwnOTyKhDKllozS08mqoE0-C6OACKBCOVM%20y67hUAQAL1yCCEDPNGqB6phbqBcF0VFEOtZmnu%20F%20ECNJvBkOhrLQUAgZXtFKlQgE%20FEn3teKhLu4HuzRgcM28AoesIRL2G%20AEkmThuNpoCQXo9yeLxgoV4CbTigA5HDEfcu-kYSVyli6zxVQnWZ2EF3iaSqAPLVxhxUqmOl2jJ1LCdOuwKhepRVAuxvXYPt1xZOfKY5r4Stzvsvau1rYAu72jbzCr05ZN5JPCQiELWCBZMgABigHASaIStFQQSKOWIS9GkTjeGBkFAaGQiNg8zy2AwrS9mWQSVtW2G9BsQA)

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work based on my tests so far. Also, additional thanks for your explanation of how you helped Typescript to 'understand' the complicated expression! The only minor thing is, I think you changed `ObjectArrKeys` in the playground link to also allow non-object arrays, so in this case, all arrays would be permitted (e.g. `string[]`) as `children` fields. This is a minor fix though, by just changing it back to the definition I had originally.